# Want to run external shell script in HAProxy

Tags: load-balancing, haproxy

I have set the load balancer of LDAP using HAProxy.The challenge is I want to integrate a shell script I have written for a health check to haproxy.cfg.
I have tried many options available in blogs but not working. below is my haproxy.cfg file please help me.

```
# LDAP and LDAP/STARTTLS
frontend ldap_service_front
  mode                  tcp
  log                   global
  bind                  *:389
  description           LDAP Service
  option                tcplog
  option                logasap
  option                socket-stats
  option                tcpka
  timeout client        5s
  default_backend       ldap_service_back
backend ldap_service_back
  option external-check
  external-check path "/usr/bin:/bin"
  external-check command "/bin/ldapHealthCheck.sh"
server                ldap-1 x.x.x:389 check fall 1 rise 1 inter 2s
  server                ldap-2 x.x.x:389 check fall 1 rise 1 inter 2s
  mode                  tcp
  balance               leastconn
  timeout server        30s
  timeout connect       30s
  timeout queue         30s
  option                tcpka
  option                tcp-check
  tcp-check             connect port 389
```

Comment: *"but not working"* ...in what sense is it not working?  Is the configuration rejected?  Does the health check unexpectedly always pass or always fail?  Are errors logged?  Are you running with `chroot` and have perhaps failed to consider the implications of that?

Comment: @Michael-sqlbot : Thanks for the response, I was getting below warning [WARNING] 014/131459 (20370) : config : 'external-check command' will be ignored for backend 'ldap_service_back' (requires 'option external-check').
Jan 15 13:14:59 ip-10-0-25-177 haproxy: [WARNING] 014/131459 (20370) : config : 'external-check path' will be ignored for backend 'ldap_service_back' (requires 'option external-check').

Comment: @Michael-sqlbot: After adding beow 
 listen up
        bind *:389
        option external-check
        external-check command /bin/ldapHealthCheck.sh
        server srv ad1.valhalla.phdata.io:389 check inter 1000
the warning is no more seen, But the problem is i am not able to get the expected output in the /var/log/messages/ the output should be 
LDAP is running.
 HTTP/1.1 200 OK